# Result returned less 1 (minus 1) from the exact row available in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
<?php

include 'db.php';

$subassetcategory = $_GET["subassetcategory"];

if ($subassetcategory == "all") {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM asset_subasset";
}
else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM asset_subasset WHERE subassetcategory = '" . $subassetcategory . "'";
}

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
            <th>Asset ID</th>
            <th>Subasset Category</th>
            <th>Subasset Name</th>
            </tr>";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $subassetid = $row['subassetid'];
        $assetid = $row['assetid'];
        $subassetname = $row['subassetname'];
        $subassetcategory = $row['subassetcategory'];

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $assetid . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $subassetcategory . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $subassetname . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<a href='viewassetdetail.php?subassetid=$subassetid&assetid=$assetid'>View<a/>" . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
else {
    echo "<br> No data found </br>";
}

mysql_close($connect);

?>
```

Please help me, I couldn't figure out as to why this code cannot return the result properly. It returned less 1 row (if result suppose to have 2 rows it will only return 1) from the exact rows available in the database.

```
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
            <th>Asset ID</th>
            <th>Subasset Category</th>
            <th>Subasset Name</th>
            </tr>";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $subassetid = $row['subassetid'];
        $assetid = $row['assetid'];
        $subassetname = $row['subassetname'];
        $subassetcategory = $row['subassetcategory'];

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $assetid . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $subassetcategory . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $subassetname . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<a href='viewassetdetail.php?subassetid=$subassetid&assetid=$assetid'>View<a/>" . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
else {
    echo "<br> No data found </br>";
}

mysql_close($connect);

?>
```

if I just wrote this code, it works perfectly.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Asset ID</th>
    <th>Subasset Category</th>
    <th>Subasset Name</th>
    </tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $subassetid = $row['subassetid'];
    $assetid = $row['assetid'];
    $subassetname = $row['subassetname'];
    $subassetcategory = $row['subassetcategory'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $assetid . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $subassetcategory . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $subassetname . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<a href='viewassetdetail.php?subassetid=$subassetid&assetid=$assetid'>View<a/>" . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($connect);

?>
```

But I want it to show "No data found" if the result was empty. So, any help? I know it's very simple but I couldn't find the answer for days already. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically slicing off the first result in your if statement:

```
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

Just check for the number of rows returned to keep the resultset intact:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
```

Comment: oh that was fast!! thanks so much!! I know it must be something very simple but yeah, I still couldn't figure it out until now. Really appreciate it!! peace!! =)

Comment: Ok, I already got that works from 1st answer(konsolenfreddy) but everyone, thank you so much, really appreciate all of your response!! now I'm a bit embarrass coz it's something very trivial right? but look at how many people answers, in an instant...=P

Comment: @crystalz I'm glad I could help. As you're new to SO, you might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/faq regarding accepting an answer. This will help other people who have a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

You have use `mysql_fetch_array()` to check if there is any result. You have already consumed one row there. So, that is where your one missing row is. You can check if there is any value in the result by using `mysql_num_rows()`

Answer (score 0):

```
If ($result->num_rows() > 0 ) { do your stuff } else { no results found }
```

Answer (score 0):

A little more streamlined way of doing it would be to check the result set before you even get into looping the array.  That way you can skip all that if its empty and go straight to the empty dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  .....................
}
```

try to use this:

```
 $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); //returns the number of rows selected

 if($num_rows==0)
 {
      //no data
 }
 else
 {
    //your code
 }
```